# Obfuscation of Javascript identifiers without touching line breaks

Tags: javascript, compression, obfuscation

I develop a proprietary Javascript program. I don't want it's code to be reused by anyone. So it should be obfuscated some way. But if an exception happens user should be able to bring stack trace from browser Javascript console and send it to me and I want to see in it original line numbers - same as in not obfuscated code.

So I want to obfuscate only identifiers, but don't touch line breaks. Do you know any tool for this? All obfuscators I know also compress Javascript, eliminating some line breaks and empty lines.

If there is no such, may be you can advice an obfuscator which I can most easily adapt for my needs

Comment: Look into Source Maps.

Comment: @elclanrs It is a solution, but not ideal, because I don't even need to compress Javascript, only to obfuscate, so such complication like introducing source maps will not add much value, though it has 2 advantages: 1) it's standard approach, 2) with it also character number in stacktrace line can be reported